# How can I do masked input using React Admin?

Tags: react-admin

I'm using

```
<TextField source="phone" />
```

But I want to format the input to use masked input for phone format.

Answer (score 1):

`react-admin` components render `MUI` components.
You can read about masking inputs in their documentation:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries